# How to configure openshift route & router to expose public service

Tags: openshift, haproxy, openshift-origin

I have an openshift origin cluster running in aws.
I deployed a "hello world!" application with the web console.
the default route has been created: `http://demo-demo.router.default.svc.cluster.local/`
this route is only available in the cluster.

Assuming I have a domain `www.example.com`, How to create a public route and configure it to work with my domain?

I found many docs about route and router openshift but I cant make it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml`:

```
routingConfig:
  subdomain: apps.example.com
```

and restart openshift master.

```
systemctl restart atomic-openshift-master-api atomic-openshift-master-controllers
```

Then new routes will be named `$SVC-$NAMESPACE.apps.example.com`.

Comment: is that enough? apps.example.com should be redirected to openshift master i guess?

Comment: If your client-side DNS server can't recognize apps.example.com, you need to add an entry in client host's /etc/hosts, so that xxx-xxx.apps.example.com will be redirected to openshift router.

Comment: /etc/hosts file doesn't support wildcards, we can do that with dnsmasq for example